# No Calendar Event has been set issue

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, ekevent, ekeventstore

I have an issue regarding to EKEventEditViewController while add any event via my app.
When I'll install the app for the first time I can not add event and the issue of No calendar event has been set comes with "Error Domain=EKErrorDomain Code=1".
It will comes only whenever app is opened for the first time with different bundle Identifier.
It will works perfectly when I'll install the app for the next time and I can add the event.
I have also checked the condition of requestAccessToEntityType:completion: before adding the event.
I am stuck at this point and tried every method which I found by googling.

-Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time when the app is asking for permissions the prompt is not blocking the app, and the proper way to add the event is inside of the completion block

Here is one example :

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Event creation code HERE!!! (for the first run only) this block will not be executed for the next runs
    });
}];
```

Most probably your event creation code is after the **requestAccessToEntityType** function and not inside of the completion block.

You cannot create event for the first time because the access is only allowed when the completion block is executed.

And once you granted access for the next run the access is allowed and all is working as expected.